# Import an html card class to a google sheet

Tags: html, google-sheets

I used to scrape some data from a website onto a google sheet using `importhtml(URL, "table", INDEX)`. But recently, website changed from displaying the data in a table, to displaying it as a `class = card` element. Is there still some way to import the data from that card to a google sheet? Perhaps with a script?

Concrete example: using `=IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketscreener.com/quote/stock/APPLE-INC-4849/consensus/","table",0)` in a google sheets cell would import a table with Analysts' consensus data, but no it does not work any more.

Comment: The formula you shared works and I even changed the INDEX and I'm able to retrieve the information, but I would appreciate if you would share some screenshots or explain more about what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,importxml(A1,"//*[@id='consensusdetail']/div[2]"),
     Λ,regexreplace(Σ,"(Sell|Mean consensus|Number of Analysts|Last Close Price|Average target price|Spread / Average Target|High Price Target|Spread / Highest target|Low Price Target|Spread / Lowest Target)","|$1"),
     index(split(tocol(split(Λ,"|")),"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, baffling to me that that works :D, love the fish emojis too! This is exactly what I wanted, thanks!